# typeerror 'bytes' object is not callable

Tags: python, byte, typeerror

**My code:**

```
import psycopg2
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib.parse
uname = " **** "
pwd = " ***** "
resp = requests.get("https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/skus/SKUID/listings", auth=(uname, pwd))
con_page = resp.content()
print (con_page)
```

**I am getting this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Prime\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Fp_API\src\fp_api.py", line 18, in <module>

    con_page = resp.content()

TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable
```

Comment: It seems to be saying that 'content' is not a function, but actually of type 'bytes'. Try removing the parentheses.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response), the return value of `requests.get()` is a `requests.Response`, which has a `content` field with the type `bytes`, rather than a `content()` method.

Try this instead:

```
con_page = resp.content
```

Answer (score -1):

do this:
con_page = resp.content.decode()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read How to Answer and edit your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.