# beautiful soup TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**My code**

```
page = requests.get(URL).content()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")
prices = soup.find("span", class_="value hidden-xs").encode
for row in prices('div',
                        attrs = {'class':'col-md-6 col-xs-12'}):
    price = {}

    price['url'] = row.span['data-value']

    prices.append(price)
print(prices)
```

**The output:**

```
line 6, in <module>
    page = requests.get(URL).content()
TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable
```

This is my first project with python and beautiful soup so I will be thankful if you explain what is wrong with it
I did try the solution in [typeerror 'bytes' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499836/typeerror-bytes-object-is-not-callable) but I think it doesn't work for python 3

and when I tried it without `.content` it gives:

```
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()
```

**When I run this code:**

```
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")
prices = soup.find("span", class_="value hidden-xs").encode('utf-8')
print(prices)
```

**Outputs:**

```
b'<span class="value hidden-xs" data-value="1910.2">\xdb\xb1\xdb\xb9\xdb\xb1\xdb\xb0.\xdb\xb2</span>'
```

I need to collect value of 9 of this "data-value"s and put them in an array

Comment: So, did you try without the parenthesis for `content`?

Comment: "I did try the solution in typeerror 'bytes' object is not callable" Okay, and in order to try that solution, exactly how did you change the code? After changing the code like that and running it again, what happened? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: And why did you lose `.content` now? That solution clearly had it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
page = requests.get(URL)
# ^^^^ this a response object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")
prices = soup.find("span", class_="value hidden-xs").encode('utf-8')
print(prices)
```

When you're using `requests.get` function you are being returned a `Response` object. Response object has various attributes like status code, headers, url and `text` or `content` attribute which contains document data in either string (text) or bytes (content).

In your example you should use:

```py
response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
prices = soup.find("span", class_="value hidden-xs").encode('utf-8')
print(prices)
```

For full introduction to using BeautifulSoup in Python see my blog article [Web Scraping with Python and BeautifulSoup](https://scrapfly.io/blog/web-scraping-with-python-beautifulsoup/)